# Hazelcast mapLoad does not update cache

Tags: hibernate, caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am trying to implement Hazelcast query cache

```
MyEntityMapLoader implements ApplicationContextAware, MapLoader<MyEntityMapLoader.CompositeKey, List<BigInteger>> {
    @Inject
    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;
    @Inject
    MyEntityRepository myRepo;
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
     //initialize map
    }
@Override
    @Transactional
    public Map<CompositeKey, List<BigInteger>> loadAll(Collection<CompositeKey> keys) {
        return buildMap(getAll());
    }
```

I am also implementing other methods from the interface com.hazelcast.core.MapLoader>

I am using CrudRepository to perform CRUD operations on MyEntity. On the application startup, the cache is loaded and shows up to date data.
Problem occurs when I add/delete using my CrudRepo, the Hazelcast seems to not know. i still see old data.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [MapLoader](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MapLoader.html)which brings items into memory but doesn't send them out again on change.

You need to swap to [MapStore](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MapStore.html) which brings items into memory on demand, and also sends them out again on change.

*MapLoader* provides `load(K)`. *MapStore* extends *MapLoader* to provide `store(K,V)` and `delete(K)`